# Создание подгрупп в QTableWdiget или QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qtablewidget, qtreewidget

Я хочу сделать таблицу с подгруппами, которые можно будет сворачивать и разворачивать. К примеру есть список людей и их нужно распределить по специальностям. Я думаю можно создавать для каждой группы отдельную таблицу и тогда останется только добавить 'сворачивание' `QTableWdiget`, но в таком случае будет множество объектов (таблиц) и мне кажется это неверным.

Также я пробовала вариант с `QTreeWidget`, но мне не удалось вставить в него таблицы в виде элементов или найти примеры с такой реализацией. Я постаралась показать что требуется на примере одной таблицы.

Строки таблицы зелёного цвета по задумке должны быть заголовками подгрупп:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при надобности их можно 'свернуть', то есть спрятать все строки в подгруппе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код для примера:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


positions = ['Бухгалтеры', 'Строители', 'Менеджеры']
humans = [
    {'name': 'Maria Schlager', 'age': 24},
    {'name': 'John Townsley', 'age': 56},
    {'name': 'Jeremy Villella', 'age': 32}
]


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow')
        self.resize(450, 450)
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)

        table = self.tableWidget
        header = table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QTableWidgetItem('Имя и фамилия'))
        table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, QTableWidgetItem('Возраст'))

        for p in positions:
            row_position = table.rowCount()
            table.insertRow(row_position)
            table.setItem(row_position, 0, QTableWidgetItem('Специальность'))
            table.setItem(row_position, 1, QTableWidgetItem(p))
            table.item(row_position, 0).setBackground(QtCore.Qt.green)
            table.item(row_position, 1).setBackground(QtCore.Qt.green)
            for h in humans:
                row_position = table.rowCount()
                table.insertRow(row_position)
                table.setItem(row_position, 0, QTableWidgetItem(h['name']))
                table.setItem(row_position, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(h['age'])))

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам предложу вернуться к реализации задуманного вами через `QTreeWidget`.

```
import  sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget)
        
        positions = [
            [
              ['Специальность', 'Бухгалтеры'], 
              [
                ['Maria Schlager', '24'], 
                ['John Townsley', '56'],
                ['Jeremy Villella', '32'],
              ]
            ], 
            [['Специальность', 'Строители'], 
             [
              ['Стивенсон Томас', '203'], 
              ['Игнатченко Евгений Афанасьевич', '115'],
             ]
            ], 
            [['Специальность', 'Менеджеры'], [['Афродита', '21'], ]],
        ]

        self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(['Имя и фамилия', 'Возраст'])
        self.treeWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.change_func)

        for header, lines in positions:
            preview = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget) 
            self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(preview)
            preview.setText(0, header[0])
            preview.setText(1, header[1])

            for line in lines:
                preview.addChild(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(line))

        self.treeWidget.expandAll()         

    def change_func(self, item, column):
        print(column, item.text(column))
       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 600)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]